# How do i get the specific values from json data in React

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting an error in console while i am trying to get a specific value from json data. This is the error:

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processen_id' of undefined'

Here is my code:

```
$.get("/getProces", function (data) {
        if (data.error) {
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i <= data.message.length; i++) {
                var obj = data.message[i]
                console.log(obj.processen_id)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is what i get when i log (data):

[image: console.log(data)]

Comment: Have you tried logging `data` and `data.message` to see what's inside? Obviously the `message[i]` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code in the for loop

> <= instead of <

```
 $.get("/getProces", function (data) {
            if (data.error) {
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data.message[i]
                    console.log(obj.processen_id)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `obj` is undefined. That means, that `data.message[i]` gets an undefined value. The problem is the loop. You get an `i` that is larger then the array. Change `<=` to `<`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
   var obj = data.message[i]
   console.log(obj.processen_id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

index out of range: `for (var i = 0; i <= data.message.length; i++) {`  should be `for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {` instead.

you can also optimize your code in this way:

```js
$
  .get("/getProces")
  .then((res) => res.error ? Promise.reject(res) : Promise.resolve(res))
  .then((data) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
      var obj = data.message[i]
      console.log(obj.processen_id)
    }
  })
```